# Datatable select time in smalldatetime column

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, smalldatetime

I have a `datatable` with 4 columns and one of them is `smalldatetime` type. When I retrieve datatable from SQL base, I would like to query further through `datatable`, but only by a specific time. Is this possible?

I am tryin with something like this:

```
DataRow[] rows = dataset.Tables[0].Select("resStart = 'some date '" + myTime+"'");
```

and specifically I am trying to navigate through dates and times in datagrid so finally it dhould retreive one row by query like this

```
DataRow[] rows = dataset.Tables[0].Select("resStart = '" + myDate +" " + myTime+"'");
```

Comment: You really need to provide more details. I don't even get the question. The obvious answer is "yes" but I guess it's not what you're expecting.

Comment: You need to show the code you are using to retrieve from database.  Basically you want to add a `where` clause with a `between` on the column.

Comment: Select  * from tbale name Where CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Colum_Name,8) = 'Your Spcifictime here'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want *to query your data within your sourceCode* DataTable class supports **method SELECT** which allows you to filter your table according to a given condition. Check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx) for a detailed explanation.

```
string filterExpression = "YOUR_SMALLDATE_COLUMN > #1/1/00#";
DataRow[] rows = YOUR_DATATABLE_VAR.Select(filterExpression);

// eg. print out results - or rebind data etc.
for(int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i ++)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(rows[i]["ANY_COLUMN_NAME"]);
}
```

Of course, you may also change your select statement to the database and **append a [whereClause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188047.aspx)**.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible?

Yes of course. For example by using Linq-To-DataSet:

```
var thisYearsRows = table
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<DateTime>("SmalldateTimeField").Year == DateTime.Now.Year);
```

You need to add `using System.Linq;` and a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll`.